# How to lock in a cell value after a specific date has passed

Tags: excel, vba, database, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that allows me to add numbers together, and these numbers change everyday [=SUM(G5:G12)]

Column A has a date for everyday in 2021 and column B is where I’d like to paste the value of G13.

What I want to be able to do is copy G13 (which has the sum of G5:G12) to column B automatically without changing the previous days value.

My current formula is: =IFERROR(IF(A2:A366=TODAY(),G13,0),0)

It works for today however when I updated the value of G13 today, yesterday’s value became 0. Is there a way to lock the previous values so they never change?

Comment: You use the words "copy" and "paste", but you're not using copy/paste in your approach at all. For a formula approach, we don't see enough of your spreadsheet to provide a better solution. What should the cell show if the date is not today?? Edit your question, provide a screenshot with a few more scenarios, i.e. yesterday, tomorrow, mock up the expected results and explain in context. Post a comment when you have edited your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use VBA or something a little less elegant / robust (e.g. pivot table).

### VBA option

I explain the code below: *Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)* - if you change the the variable '*Target*' here, make sure you change it below when setting it to G13 (or other 'target cell'), i.e.:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Set Target = Range("G13")
col_index = 1
```

The *target* cell ('G13'): is what you want to 'hard copy' / make static. *col_index* represents which column in which you want it to go. In actuality, as an offset function is used, *col_index* = column number corresponding to where hardcopy of G13 goes, less one.  Less one is just a quirk with offset function, since offset(A1,1,1) will move the reference cell to B2 (i.e. one down, one to right).  In this case (screenshot below), contents of cell G13 is placed in cell B14, i.e. column B (so col_index = 2 - 1 = 1) and row 14 (taken care of by the match() - 1.  If you wanted the 'hardcopy' to go into column C, then use col_index = 3 - 1 = 2, and so on.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Offset(Application.Match(Date * 1, Columns(col_index), 0) - 1, col_index).Value = Target.Value
```

Change cell G13 to any desired cell you want to have 'hard-copied' (provided its in the same active sheet - although minor modifications could be made to account for working across sheets - let me know! :)

### Summary

- VBA uses function (offset/match) to find relevant cell to place
  'target'
- Today's date (1xDate) return serial number (found this to be
  easier when looking up corresponding cell in column with dates using
  an offset,match function)
- Can change cell G13, and / or *col_index* or the name *'Target'* (so long as you change this consistently throughout the code, as req.)

### Complete Code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   Set Target = Range("G13")
   col_index = 1
   ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Offset(Application.Match(Date*1,Columns(col_index), 0) - 1, col_index).Value = Target.Value
End Sub
```

### Steps

1. Open VB (alt + F11) - windows CPU
2. Find the sheet in question in project explorer menu, and double click to open the window pane for writing VB code
3. At the top of this pane there'll be 2 drop downs - select "Worksheet" from the left menu dropdown, and "SelectionChange" from the right (a Private Sub_SelectionChange() followed by 'End Sub' will appear.
4. Modify this to look like above.

Voila! Now every time the value in "G13" changes, the appropriate day should automatically update.

### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much James! Would you be able to explain the code to me (just in case I need to add more columns at a later stage so I would know which parts of the code would need to be modified?) Thanks again! This is so helpful

Comment: Hi user153... np - have modified response above to explain each bit in a little more detail. Trust in order - let me know if you still have questions/get stuck with anything,

Comment: Let me know if that was/wasn't what you were hoping for pls .- and best of luck with your exercise/endeavours! :)

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you so so much - this is exactly what I needed :)

Comment: Glad to hear! best of luck with your project/code, keep safe!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the equals today to less than or equals today (i.e. change + to <=):

`=IFERROR(IF(A2:A366<=TODAY(),G13,0),0)`

Comment: Oh, Okay. This might actually work - I'll have to test it tomorrow and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: If in B1 the value copied from G13 today was 15, and tomorrow the value of G13 is 5, I want to ensure that B2 (tomorrow) says 5 and B1 remains as 15 - do you know if this will ensure that? I'm just trying to understand the logic of adding <. Thanks!

Comment: Ah ok. The < simply stops it from turning to 0 in the if statement. In order to save the previous values, you'll need to hard-code them as you go. You could make that process a one-button press with a macro, but would still need to open the spreadsheet and hit the button

Comment: Okay thanks so much! Would you happen to have any resources/videos to help me make that process?

Comment: Looks like James has got you covered :)