# Date functions in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I want to keep track Date and Time of the data when it was put into the cell. Like, tracking ids of shipments will be scan in cell A1, and in cell A2, date and time will be recorded.

Comment: A formula will not do this reliably.  You will want vba in a worksheet change event.

Answer (score 0):

♣ Solved ♣

You can deploy something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66631690/13607672) solution, which, per @SC's comment, relies on a "change event" VB method.

It's not exactly a repeat of the above link however, as that was more specific / bespoke for a specific setup, whilst your query is quite general (albeit somewhat vague).

Ta,
J